# Как выбрать все input с одним атрибутом name и записать в массив их значения?

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Доброго вечера. У меня возникла задача выбрать выбрать все input с одним атрибутом name и записать в массив их значения, а потом удалить все пустые значения. Так как одинаковые формы добавляются на одной странице и добавлять id у формы нет смысла, так как одинаковый id у форм, на одной страницы, это ошибка. Использую Jquery и такой вариант : `var phone = $('input[name=\'phone\']').attr('value');` добавляет пустое значение в переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так. Только хотел бы предостеречь от использования одинаковых `name` у `input`, во избежание всяких ошибок.

```js
    var phones = $('input[name*="phone"]');
    var arr = [];

    phones.each(function() {
      if (this.value != "") {
        arr.push(this.value);
      }
    });


    console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="phone1" value="53453466456456" />
<input name="phone2" value="854634545" />
<input name="phone3" value="" />
<input name="phone4" value="4236456" />
```

Comment: спасибо !!!.... этот вариант подошел, сам бы еще думал как это сделать

Comment: "Только хотел бы предостеречь от использования одинаковых name у input" - я это понимаю, но дело в том что я делаю интеграцию на заказ и у них, к сожалению, этого разработчики не учли

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {

  var phones = [];
  $('input[name="phone"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      phones.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  console.log(phones);
  $('.res').text(phones);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="100-500">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="(095) 000-99-33">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="(044) 155-66-77">
<input type="text" name="phone" value="30-66-99">

<br>Результат:
<div class="res"></div>
```

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Дописал обработку пустых инпутов.

Comment: ну да ...ваши варианты очень похожи

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать несколькими способам, вот два из них:

```
  $('input[name="name"]').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });
  $('input[name="name"]').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; });
```

Вернут массив input'ов с именем name и пустым value.